# Errors attempting to run XQuery scripts for single sign on into MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

I'm working on using an xquery re-writer script to automate the login for a Single Sign-On solution. I'm starting with the Admin App Server at port 8001. In the App Server configuration I have:

- Set authentication = `application-level`
- Set url rewriter = `rewriter.xqy`

I have also set the following `rewriter.xqy` script at the root `Admin/` directory on the server.
As you can see, just as a simple test, I'm attempting to programmatically login as user "Austin" (a valid user).

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace rest = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/rest"
    at "/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/rest.xqy";

import module namespace config = "http://marklogic.com/admin/endpoint-config"
    at "/endpoints/config.xqy";

xdmp:login("Austin")

return (rest:rewrite($config:OPTIONS,"uri"),xdmp:get-request-url())[1]
```

However, after recycling the webserver, I keep getting the following error when browsing to the Admin UI.
As soon as I remove the `xdmp` line, the error goes away, and I can get straight in.

```
500: Internal Server Error
XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected QName_
In /rewriter.xqy on line 9
```

As another test, I tried to log some messages using `xdmp:log`, but those lines are also failing.
Any clue why xdmp scripts are not running successfully?

Answer (score 3):

In XQuery a `return` is only part of a [FLWOR expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLWOR). It's not a procedural return. You can just execute a sequence here:

```
xdmp:login("Austin"),
(rest:rewrite($config:OPTIONS,"uri"),xdmp:get-request-url())[1]
```

I can't vouch that this logic is sound, but the syntax is.

Comment: Thanks Hunter. Unfortunately, removing the `return` is still giving me errors. All errors reference the line where the `xdmp:login()` command are. And if I try to put an `xdmp:log("Test")` above it, then that line throws the error instead.

Comment: @Ryan Miller don't overlook the fact that you need to add a comma `,` separating the xdmp:login() and that other statement. It's a sequence of statements. Without the comma separating them, you will get a syntax error