# Unable to run XQuery scripts in URL Rewriter for MarkLogic SSO

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I'm working on using an XQuery re-writer script to automate the login for a Single Sign-On solution. I'm starting with the Admin App Server at port 8001. In the App Server configuration I have:

Set authentication = `application-level`
Set url rewriter = `rewriter.xqy`

I have also set the following rewriter.xqy script at the root Admin/ directory on the server. As you can see, just as a simple test, I'm attempting to programmatically login as user "Austin" (a valid user).

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace rest = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/rest"
    at "/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/rest.xqy";

import module namespace config = "http://marklogic.com/admin/endpoint-config"
    at "/endpoints/config.xqy";

xdmp:login("Austin")

(rest:rewrite($config:OPTIONS,"uri"),xdmp:get-request-url())[1]
```

However, after recycling the webserver, I keep getting the following error when browsing to the Admin UI.
As soon as I remove the xdmp line, the error goes away, and I can get straight in.

> 500: Internal Server Error
> XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected QName_
> In /rewriter.xqy on line 9

As another test, I tried to log some messages using `xdmp:log("test")`, but those lines are also failing.
Any clue why xdmp scripts are not running successfully?

Comment: the syntax error is because you need a comma separating the sequence of two commands 1. the `xdmp:login()` and 2. the other sequence of commands executing rest:rewrite() and xdmp:get-request-url() in which the first item is returned. So, add a comma `,` after the login

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Errors attempting to run XQuery scripts for single sign on into MarkLogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65816993/errors-attempting-to-run-xquery-scripts-for-single-sign-on-into-marklogic)